# Python install several external libraries and run through one file

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, egg

I have a Python program that requires the install of 4 external libraries. This program needs to be given to other people to run who may not have any command line experience so giving them commands to enter is not really an option.

Is there a way I can package all these libraries into one file so they can execute easier without the need to do several installs?

I have researched and experimented with **distutils, setuptools** and python **eggs** but could not get the file running on another machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Comment: What platform will the other people be running it on? There's PyInstaller, Py2Exe, and various other options.

Comment: I did research py2exe, but it has to be able to run on a linux machine as well

Comment: Are you sure all 4 external libs are python-only?   If not, you'll have to distribute multiple versions of the libs.

Comment: Yes, all the libs are python only

Answer (score 0):

If you are using files on pypi.python.org (PyPI)

```
import pip
for x in ['list', 'of', 'packages']:
    pip.main(['install', x)
```

`['list', 'of', 'packages']` being a list of packages to be installed.

If you not are using PyPI, than there is no relevant way of installing a module